# Tabela zebrada em cinza e branco

Tags: javascript, html

Estou resolvendo um exercício de faculdade, e estou com problemas em passar a cor exata para uma tabela zebrada.

Fiz a função desse modo, porém na hora da tabela ser construída, ela está saindo em verde e amarelo:

```
function rowValue(list) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            list[i][5] = '#4F4F4F';
        }
        else {
            list[i][5] = '#FFFFFF';
        }

    }
}
```

E a montagem da tabela desse modo:

```
function buildTable(list, id) {
    var html = "<thead> " +
        " <tr> " +
        " <th scope='col'>Proprietário</th> " +
        " <th scope='col'>Endereço</th> " +
        " <th scope='col'>Valor</th>" +
        " <th scope='col'>Aluguel</th>" +
        " <th scope='col'>Taxa</th>" +
        " </tr>" +
        "</thead>" +
        "<tbody>";

    rowValue(list);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

        html += "<tr bgcolor = " + list[i][5] + ";>" +
            "<td>" + list[i][0] + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + list[i][1] + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + list[i][2] + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + list[i][3] + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + list[i][4] + "</td>" +
            "</tr>";
    }

    html += "</tbody>";
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow Ravel. Amigo, qual é a sua dúvida? Tente ser mais claro e objetivo. Valeu!

Comment: Valeu Felipe! Estou com o problema no qual as cores da tabela saem em verde e amarelo, não em cinza em branco como eu determinei na criação da função, olhei em vários sites para ver se não estava errando no hexadecimal.

Comment: Porquê reinventar a roda ? Você pode dar esse estilo "zebrado" pelo css utilizando o pseudo seletor `:nth-child(odd)` ou `:nth-child(even)`

Comment: @Isac, estamos fazendo exercícios para treinar o uso de funções e ter mais familiaridade com a linguagem! Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu erro está no ponto e vírgula `;` que você está juntando ao hexadecimal:

```
html += "<tr bgcolor = " + list[i][5] + ";>" +
                                         ↑
```

Está resultando em valor inválido, desta forma:

```
bgcolor="#4F4F4F;"
                ↑
```

Quando o correto seria:

```
bgcolor="#4F4F4F"
```

Então basta retirar o `;`:

```js
function rowValue(list) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            list[i][5] = '#4F4F4F';
        }
        else {
            list[i][5] = '#FFFFFF';
        }

    }
}

function buildTable(list, id) {
    var html = "<thead> " +
        " <tr> " +
        " <th scope='col'>Proprietário</th> " +
        " <th scope='col'>Endereço</th> " +
        " <th scope='col'>Valor</th>" +
        " <th scope='col'>Aluguel</th>" +
        " <th scope='col'>Taxa</th>" +
        " </tr>" +
        "</thead>" +
        "<tbody>";

    rowValue(list);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

        html += "<tr bgcolor = " + list[i][5] + ">" +
            "<td>" + list[i][0] + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + list[i][1] + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + list[i][2] + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + list[i][3] + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + list[i][4] + "</td>" +
            "</tr>";
    }

    html += "</tbody>";
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;
}

var lista = [
   ['a','b','c','d','e'],
   ['a','b','c','d','e']
];
buildTable(lista,'teste');
```

```html
<table id="teste"></table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Estava achando que tinha algum erro na minha lógica!